# Django calling methods of DetailView and RedirectView in template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get into Django and got stuck with `DeatailView` and `RedirectView`

I made the following template for rendering posts with enabling post detailed view and like button. When I click on either `Like` or `Detail` button none of the requests is sent. I tried changing different methods, but that didn't help either. I trying to get whether I was mistaken in the template or in view logic.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 40rem;">
        <img src = "{{ post.image.url }}" style="height: 40rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-tittle">{{post.author.username}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.description }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Likes : {{ post.likes.count }}</p>
            <p class="id">Post_id: {{ post.id }}</p>
            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Like</button>
                    </form>
                {% endif %}
                <form action="{% url 'detail' pk=post.id %}" method="GET">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Detail</button>
                </form>
                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">down</button> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Posts `views.py` file

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print(context.items())
        return context

class PostLikeUpvote(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        post_id = kwargs.get('id')
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            post.likes.add(user)
        url_redirect = post.get_redirect_url()
        return url_redirect
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('new/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='new'),
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('posts/', PostList.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('like_post/', PostLikeUpvote.as_view(), name='like_post'),
    path('posts/<pk>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('bot/webhook', csrf_exempt(BotView.as_view())),
]
```

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: The button type should be submit: `<button type="submit">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to submit the form, the type of the button should be `submit`, not `button`:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Like</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

otherwise it is a simple button that can for example run a JavaScript function, but it will not (automatically) submit the form. Of course you can write a JavaScript function to submit the form, but unless you have a specific reason for that, it is better to let the browser do the work for you.